# React - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

this is my first post. I'm new to react and learn via a tutorial. I delete the unwanted parts with loading, I get a blank site and the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fullName').

I have searched some solutions and tested things out but it will not work out. The order will be created but only the page will not display.

I really want to understand why this is happening and how to solve this.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST': // Deleted
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' }; // Deleted
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, order: action.payload, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
export default function OrderScreen() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;

  const params = useParams();
  const { id: orderId } = params;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [{ loading , error, order }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { // Deleted "loading"
    loading: true, // Deleted "loading: true"
    order: {},
    error: '',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrder = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' }); // Deleted 
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
      }
    };

    if (!userInfo) {
      return navigate('/login');
    }
    if (!order._id || (order._id && order._id !== orderId)) {
      fetchOrder();
    }
  }, [order, userInfo, orderId, navigate]);
  return loading ? ( // Deleted 
    <LoadingBox></LoadingBox> // Deleted until ") :"
  ) : error ? (
    <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Order {orderId}</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="my-3">Order {orderId}</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Shipping</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Name:</strong> {order.shippingAddress.fullName} <br />
                <strong>Address: </strong> {order.shippingAddress.address},
                {order.shippingAddress.city}, {order.shippingAddress.postalCode}
                ,{order.shippingAddress.country}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isDelivered ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Delivered at {order.deliveredAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Delivered</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Payment</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                <strong>Method:</strong> {order.paymentMethod}
              </Card.Text>
              {order.isPaid ? (
                <MessageBox variant="success">
                  Paid at {order.paidAt}
                </MessageBox>
              ) : (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">Not Paid</MessageBox>
              )}
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Items</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                {order.orderItems.map((item) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={item._id}>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                      <Col md={6}>
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                        ></img>{' '}
                        <Link to={`/product/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>
                        <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                      </Col>
                      <Col md={3}>${item.price}</Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card className="mb-3">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Order Summary</Card.Title>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Items</Col>
                    <Col>${order.itemsPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Shipping</Col>
                    <Col>${order.shippingPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Tax</Col>
                    <Col>${order.taxPrice.toFixed(2)}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <strong> Order Total</strong>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>${order.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **useEffect** block of code is called when the screen is rendered. In useEffect you are fetching order data which is asynchronous function. So it takes some time to load that data. That's why the loading was there. Without it your screen tries to render value of `order.shippingAddress.fullName` and that's not defined yet. You have 2 options to fix it:

1. return loading back, so it will not try to load undefined data.
2. check if all the data from order are loaded (every time you try to access them) and if not pass there some default values.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it helped me to understand!

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching your data from an API once the page loads but calling the values before they have been fetched is always going to give errors. You should conditionally call your values as such: `{order && order.shippingAddress && order.shippingAddress.fullName? order.shippingAddress.fullName : ""}`. This gives a default empty string values till your data is fetched.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for clarifying :)